# How to use Example Matcher with nested fields not fully filled

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, query-by-example

I've got the following structure:

```
@Document
class A {
String value1;
B b;
}

class B {
String value1;
String value2;
Integer value3;
}
```

Then I save a document with the following values:

```
{
value1: "val",
b: {
value1: "val1",
value2: "val2"
value3: 156
}
}
```

When I create an example with both values in B filled I get a match, when I fill only A.value1 and B.value1 I don't get a match. How can I make the match ingore null values in nested fields?

Search:

```
repository.findAll(Example.of(new A("val", new B("val1", null, null)))
```

Doesn't match because some of the B fields are not filled.

Search:

```
repository.findAll(Example.of(new A("val", new B("val1", "val2", 156)))
```

Matches as all the fields are filled.

Comment: Can you add an example how you perform the search now?

Comment: at your service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work by definining ExampleMatcher of your own:

```
ExampleMatcher exampleMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAll();
```

Then query would be like:

```
repository.findAll(
    Example.of(new A("val", new B("val1", null, null)), exampleMatcher));
```

See [API docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/ExampleMatcher.html#matchingAll--):

> Create a new ExampleMatcher ***including all non-null properties*** by default matching all predicates derived from the example.

Comment: @Greg Maybe you should check the reason for not compiling? What exactly does not compile?

Comment: sorry, no, it does compile.